# Не запускается mysql в docker на windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

Есть конфиг docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    mysql:
        container_name: mysql
        image: mysql:8
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "secret"
```

Папку mysql и пустую оставлял и заполненную с другой машины с такими же конфигурациями.
После docker-compose up в папку mysql записываются файлы:

```
ib_logfile1          49 125 КБ
ib_logfile101        49 125 КБ
ibdata1              12 228 КБ
tablespaces.open.1   1 КБ
tablespaces.open.2   0 КБ
```

И mysql останавливается с ошибками:

```
mysql    | Initializing database
mysql    | mysqld: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf' is ignored.
mysql    | 2018-02-05T08:23:21.832866Z 0 [Note] Basedir set to /usr/
mysql    | 2018-02-05T08:23:21.833042Z 0 [Warning] The syntax '--symbolic-links/-s' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
mysql    | 2018-02-05T08:23:21.841411Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
mysql    | 2018-02-05T08:23:21.842118Z 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --log-slave-updates work.
mysql    | libnuma: Warning: /sys not mounted or invalid. Assuming one node: No such file or directory
mysql    | mbind: Operation not permitted
mysql    | mbind: Operation not permitted
mysql    | 2018-02-05T08:23:22.741833Z 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 22 in a file operation.
mysql    | 2018-02-05T08:23:22.741908Z 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 22 means 'Invalid argument'
mysql    | 2018-02-05T08:23:22.741932Z 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: File ./ib_logfile101: 'aio write' returned OS error 122. Cannot continue operation
mysql    | 2018-02-05T08:23:22.741945Z 1 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
mysql exited with code 3
```

Comment: попробуйте в конфиг добавить `innodb_use_native_aio=0`. скорее всего файловая система не поддерживает aio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такая проблема на Windows. Это означает, что используемая вами файловая система не поддерживает aio. 
Вы можете в конфиге исправить это `innodb_use_native_aio=0`

Вы также можете эту командщу передать  в docker-compose как

```
command: --innodb_use_native_aio=0
```

Подробнее [тут](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command)

Например, в вашем случае будет так:

```
version: '2'
services:
    mysql:
        container_name: mysql
        image: mysql:8
        command: --innodb_use_native_aio=0
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "secret"
```